# nginx HLS streaming; how to have directories of media content?

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming

I have a simple `nginx` server up and running, in which I can serve HLS prepared media content (H264/AAC encoded mp4 video), below is my `nginx.conf` file.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {                
    server {
        listen 1935;  
        chunk_size 4096;
            
        application vod {
            play /opt/video/vod; # videos are placed here.
        }
    }
}
```

By visiting `rtmp://localhost/vod/video.mp4` I can play `video.mp4` stored in `/opt/video/vod`. However, I would like to organise my media in directories such as `movies` and `series` within `/opt/video/vod`. But when I do this, I can no longer play video. For example, I cannot play `rtmp://localhost/vod/series/video.mp4`.

Is there any way for this to work with `nginx`?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, I misunderstood how `HLS` works. By configuring `nginx` to serve `HLS` content through a certain path, any actual `HLS` content, so `H264`/`AAC` encoded content *sliced* into `*.ts` segments with an accompanying `*.m3u8` playlist can be played from that path. Below is `nginx.conf`.

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;

        application app {
            live on;

            # Don't allow RTMP playback
            deny play all;

            # Package streams as HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /var/www/vod; # place your content here
            hls_nested on;
            hls_fragment_naming system;
        }
    }
}
```

To prepare your `HLS` content, use `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i <input_video> -map 0 -codec:v libx264 -codec:a aac -f ssegment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts
```

Then point a media player, e.g. `VLC` at `http://<ip>/vod/playlist.m3u8` and it will play your video! This way you can divide your `vod` directory in whatever way you like, e.g. `vod/series/himym/1/1/playlist.m3u8`.

Comment: if you're not streaming your hls content from a remote source to your server then, there's no need for the rtmp module altogether, http configuration would be enough to stream existing hls (ts) files on your server.